# convert each slice of a numpy file to jpeg format with for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm beginners in python
I have a numpy file with the shapes of (200, 256, 256). I want to save each slice (:, 256, 256) with jpeg format. how can I do using a for loop ?
Thanks in advance

I tried this but for an image with the shape of (256, 256)

`your text`from PIL import Image
`your text`import numpy as np

`your text`A= np.load('image.npy'  ,allow_pickle = True)
`your text`im = Image.fromarray(A)
`your text`im.save("image.jpeg")

But I want to try this for a file with the shape of (200, 256, 256) with a for loop because I have some files like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the first dimension, extracting the image slices and saving them

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

A = np.load('image.npy' ,allow_pickle = True)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    im = Image.fromarray(A[i,:,:])
    im = im.convert("L")
    im.save(f"image_{i}.jpeg")
```

The images will be saved as `image_0.jpeg`, `image_1.jpeg`, ... etc

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I am trying this and getting one error of (OSError: cannot write mode F as JPEG) that for solving, adding one line of  ( im = im.convert("L") to convert RGB to gray scale then it save correctly. thanks

Comment: Nice catch! I modified the code posted.